# vim word complete, how to make the first one always as default

Tags: vim

I am using several word complete plugins in vim (word_complete.vim,  autocomplpop, omnicppcomplete-0.41). So far so good. It will pop up menus to let you choose which word to use, while I am typing the first characters

When I only type 2 characters, vim will set the first word in the popup menu as the default one, then you can directly press enter to use that word.

But the problem is usually 2 characters are not enough to narrow down the words to be complete. I need to type more. After my typing more than 2 characters, the default chosen word will disappear, then I have to use CTRL-N or CTRL-P to choose the word, although it is the first one in the popup menu.

Below is shows what I have:
The first is when I only type 2 characters

[image]

But after the third character is typed in, it appears as:

[image]

although "airline_detect_whitespace" is what i what to choose, I still need to type CTRL-N to choose it.

I am asking is there a way to configure the way vim chooses its default matcher?
for example, I want to type 5 characters before the default chosen word disappears.
Or is there a way to always make the first one in the popup menu to be chosen by default?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Make Vim completion popup menu work just like in an IDE](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Make_Vim_completion_popup_menu_work_just_like_in_an_IDE) page on the Vim Tips Wiki. It describes the setup to achieve this. Especially these mappings should create the behavior you want: Always have one menu entry pre-selected.

```
inoremap <expr> <C-n> pumvisible() ? '<C-n>' :
\ '<C-n><C-r>=pumvisible() ? "\<lt>Down>" : ""<CR>'

inoremap <expr> <M-,> pumvisible() ? '<C-n>' :
\ '<C-x><C-o><C-n><C-p><C-r>=pumvisible() ? "\<lt>Down>" : ""<CR>'
```

Comment: I tried this, but it fails to work. Thanks for your pointing out the direction i will head for.

Answer (score 0):

Those three plugins have overlapping features and certainly conflicting mappings for the pop-up menu and autocommands and stuff.

For example, AutoComplPop does everything wordcomplete does in a smarter and more automated way. OmniCPPComplete, has an obviously better C++ completion algorithm than the default one in Vim (and thus AutoComplPop's one) and can be set to not perform autocompletion.

I'd suggest you remove wordcomplete from your config, disable OmniCPPComplete's "may complete" feature and let AutoComplPop deal with the "autocompletion" side of the problem.

Comment: now, i removed word_complete.vim and the problem is still there. Anyway, I don't want to disable "may complete" feature, as I do need that feature.

Comment: well, you have three plugins all doing the same thing in slightly different ways. One of them or a combination is giving you an unwanted effect so the first thing to do before asking strangers is binary search to identify the source of the issue. Did you do that?

Comment: thanks for your response. now I have only AutoComplPop left.  the problem is still there. I need to dig into that.